# Adding curried closure as static property with expando metaclass loses default parameter value

Tags: groovy, static-methods, default-value, expando

I encountered this in both Groovy 1.8.6 and 2.0.0.

So these scenarios all work as expected:

```
def ay = { one, two=[:] -> [one, two] }
def be = { one, two, three=[:] -> [one,two,three] }
def ayprime = ay.curry('PRIME')
def beprime = be.curry('PRIME')
def beprimer = be.curry('PRIME', 'PRIMER')

assert ay(1,2) == [1,2]
assert ay(1) == [1,[:]]
assert be(1,2,3) == [1,2,3]
assert be(1,2) == [1,2,[:]]

assert ayprime(1) == ['PRIME', 1]
assert ayprime() == ['PRIME', [:]]
assert beprime(1,2) == ['PRIME', 1, 2]
assert beprime(1) == ['PRIME', 1, [:]]
assert beprimer(1) == ['PRIME', 'PRIMER', 1]
assert beprimer() == ['PRIME', 'PRIMER', [:]]
```

As does this:

```
class Klass {
    static def smethod = { one, two=[:] -> [one, two] }
}
assert Klass.smethod(1,2) == [1, 2]
assert Klass.smethod(1) == [1, [:]]
```

*This* also works, as expected:

```
Klass.metaClass.static.aymethod << ay
assert Klass.aymethod(1) == [1, [:]]
```

The default parameter to the uncurried closure survives the assignment to `Klass`.

However, **this** fails:

```
Klass.metaClass.static.ayprimemethod << ayprime
assert Klass.ayprimemethod() == ['PRIME', [:]]
```

thusly:

```
assert Klass.ayprimemethod() == ['PRIME', [:]]
             |               |
             [PRIME, null]   false
```

and similarly, this fails:

```
Klass.metaClass.static.beprimermethod << beprimer
assert Klass.beprimermethod() == ['PRIME', 'PRIMER', [:]]
```

thusly:

```
assert Klass.beprimermethod() == ['PRIME', 'PRIMER', [:]]
         |                |
         |                false
         [PRIME, PRIMER, null]
```

With the curried closures, the default parameter value works directly, but is lost when the closure is assigned as a static member of `Klass`.

This *seems* like a bug. I couldn't find this behavior documented anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior.  I also tested it as a class-instance method (so it could be tested via `Klass.metaClass.ayprimemethod << ayprime; assert new Klass().ayprimemethod() == ['PRIME', [:]]`), and found the same issue.  Looks like you should [file a bug in JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/BrowseProject.jspa?id=10242).

Comment: Done. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5621

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of currying :)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is still bothering you, i think this might be a workaround, until it gets fixed in groovy trunk. The python way to curry stuff:

```
def ayprime = { x -> x ? ay('PRIME', x) : ay('PRIME') }
def beprime = be.curry('PRIME')
def beprimer = { x -> x ? be('PRIME', 'PRIMER', x) : be('PRIME', 'PRIMER') }
```